# How to set Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item using csom

Tags: workflow, csom, publishing, content-approval

i am associating a custom workflow to a library using csom.
How do i select checkbox : Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item using csom.

Comment: Are you using 2010 or 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments
i have got the solution too. below is my code

```
clientContext.Load(web.WorkflowTemplates);
            clientContext.Load(web.Lists);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            WorkflowTemplate wfTemplate = web.WorkflowTemplates.GetByName(workFlowName);
            var wfc = new WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation();
            wfc.HistoryList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Approval Workflow History");
            wfc.Name = "Test Approval Workflow";
            wfc.TaskList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Approval Tasks");
            wfc.Template = wfTemplate;

        WorkflowAssociation wf = list.WorkflowAssociations.Add(wfc);
        wf.AllowManual = false; 
        wf.AutoStartChange = false; 
        wf.AutoStartCreate = false; 
        wf.Enabled = true;            
        wf.Update();
        clientContext.Load(wf);

        if (null != wfTemplate)
        {
            clientContext.Load(wfTemplate);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            list.EnableModeration = true;
            list.EnableMinorVersions = true;
            list.DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId = wf.Id;               

            list.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();`
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using a custom workflow, I assume you have an **Start Approval Process** action in your workflow. In this scenario, you need to do two things:

- In the workflow just before the "Start Approval Process" action set the `EnableContentApproval` workflow variable to **Yes**. Note that this workflow variable is automatically created when you add the "Start Approval Process" action to your workflow.
  [image]
- Then using CSOM (or PowerShell) set the **[DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultcontentapprovalworkflowid.aspx)** property of the **SPList** class to the id of the workflow association.
   Since you are using CSOM to associate the workflow with a library, then your code should [give you back an **SPWorkflowAssociation** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociationcollection.add.aspx) which contains the id of the workflow association. You can also get the workflow id by looping through the workflow associations of your list (see **[SPList.WorkflowAssociations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416113.aspx)**) and checking if the workflow name matches one of the associations.

#### Notes

The workflow association id changes every single time you re-associate the workflow with the library, therefore you have to also update the **DefaultContentApprovalWorkflowId** property of the library.

Comment: Doubting if SPList.WorkflowAssociations will work with 2013 workflows! :)

Comment: Also it is worth using a feature activated event receiver to associate the workflow and perform these steps.

Comment: @Nisarg, I assumed he deployed a workflow created using the 2010 platform, not 2013 platform. As far as I know, you don't have the "Start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item" in workflows created using the 2013 workflows. This option is available for out-of-the-box approval workflows and for 2010 workflows that use the "Start Approval Process" action.

Comment: Never used it, but I have seen the menu on UI..let me come back to this

Comment: Yes Nisarg, i have tired earlier with 2013 workflow but publishing is not available there. Now i am extending the approval 2010 workflow